# How do I recognize a mouse click on a line?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a WPF application. There is a canvas. I draw line when user drag the mouse over the canvas (from mouse down to mouse up). I take initial point, when mouse is pressed down and final point, when user does mouse up. Then I calculate the distance and draw the line in simple mouse down, move and up events.

After drawing many lines on canvas, I click on any one of the line. I want to select the line and show the user that line is selected (like by changing the color of the line). So user can delete it.

Thanks.

Comment: [Line class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line.aspx), just like the canvas has events like [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousedown.aspx) and so forth. You could hook up event handlers as you create them and deal with selecting the line in the handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example: (implementing what Bala suggested in his comment)

```
private void myCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Line line = new Line();

            line.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(line_MouseDown);
            line.MouseUp   += new MouseButtonEventHandler(line_MouseUp);

            line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            line.StrokeThickness = 2;
            line.X1 = 30; line.X2 = 80;
            line.Y1 = 30; line.Y2 = 30;

            myCanvas.Children.Add(line);
        }

void line_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Change line colour back to normal 
            ((Line)sender).Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        }

void line_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Change line Colour to something
            ((Line)sender).Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        }
```

Considering that you already have the logic to add the lines into canvas,

Simply add the two event handlers (as above) for every line that you add.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to add a custom MouseDown event handler to your canvas. Indeed, if your lines are very thin, you need to let the user be able to click near a line to select it.

For this, in your custom MouseDown handler, iterate over your lines and do the following:

For each line:

- Create a rectangle with the length of the line as width and height = max(lineWidth, 10px),
- Rotate your mouse coordinates around the rectangle center with an angle equals to the line angle (compute it with math.atan2),
- Check if the new mouse coordinates lie inside the rectangle,
- If so, select the current lien and break.

Comment: Hi Ribon, Thanks for your concern. Well I could not understand your step 2. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Actually, there is little chance that your lines are totally horizontal. Therefore, if you build a rectangle around them (a "oriented bounding box"), it will be rotated. Okay, now you need to know if your mouse click was done inside the rectangle. However, testing if a rectangle contains something when the rectangle is rotated is a bit complicated, so you may want to rotate your mouse coordinates by the inverse angle of the rectangle, and then test the collision with the rectangle like if it is not rotated.